# Jetty How to add a servlet to multiple ServletContextHandler or apply ContainerRequestFilter to ContextHandlerCollection

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

### I need to intercept all the requests when there are multiple ServletContextHandler configured.

I have multiple `ServletContextHandler` in a `ContextHandlerCollection` and a `ContainerRequestFilter`. 
I need this `ContainerRequestFilter` to be added to all `ServletContextHandler`
Only way I could find of adding the `ContainerRequestFilter` was through `ResourceConfig`. So I did this:

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.register(MyContainerRequestFilter.class);
ServletHolder s = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
for (Handler context : contextHandlers) {
    ((ServletContextHandler)context).addServlet(s, "/*");
}
```

which results in:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path: /*:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet$Transparent-56c0a61e

What is the right way to do this?

I also looked into handlers and tried following but it overrides all the other servlets contained in `ContextHandlerCollection` i.e., when I call /api (exists in one of the `ServletContextHandler` in `ContextHandlerCollection`), I get 404 because of `context.setContextPath("/");` below, but then this request filter needs to be applied on base path anyway.

```
HandlerWrapper wrapper = new HandlerWrapper();
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.register(RequestInterceptor.class);
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), "/*");
wrapper.setHandler(context)
HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection(true);
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{wrapper,contexts});
```

I also tried adding filter to above collection:

```
HandlerWrapper wrapper = new HandlerWrapper();
FilterHolder filter = new FilterHolder(MyContainerRequestFilter.class);  // had to implment filter interface
wrapper.addFilterWithMapping(filter, "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class)) ;
HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection(true);
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{contexts,wrapper});
```

In this case request does come to the filter but I get following exception:

> Could not send response error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Committed Committed before 404 null

Comment: _" I need this ContainerRequestFilter to be added to all ServletContextHandler"_ - What does this mean? The `ContainerRequestFilter` has no affiliation with the ServletContextHandler. It is only a Jersey component and can only be registered with Jersey. The error you are seeing is coming from your loop, where you are trying to register multiple Jersey servlets with the same mapping `/*`. What exactly are you tryin to accomplish? Often people show _HOW_ they are trying to accomplish something, and forget to tell us the _WHAT_. And sometime this leads to an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Apologies for ambiguity.Simply put,  I need to intercept all the requests when there are multiple `ServletContextHandler` configured. The approach I took was to use `ContainerRequestFilter`.

Comment: "intercept all the requests" has multiple meanings.  are you wanting behavior within a webapp? (complete with ServletContext behaviors?)  or behavior server wide (and you don't care about the ServletContext)?

Comment: Are your `ServletContextHandler` instances discovered and deployed via the `DeploymentManager`? or are they manually added to a `HandlerList` (or the older `HandlerCollection`)?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt they are manually added to `HandlerCollection`

Answer (score 0):

I could not do it with `ContainerRequestFilter` but I had to use `javax.servlet.Filter`

And the correct way to add a `javax.servlet.Filter` in my case (Multiple ServletContextHandler) is:

```
Handler[] contextHandlers = contexts.getHandlers();

for (Handler context : contextHandlers) {
        ((ServletContextHandler)context).addFilter(RequestInterceptor.class, "/*", 
EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
}
```

Comment: This isn't 1 instance of your filter for all `ServletContextHandlers`, like your question asked, this is a unique `RequestInterceptor` instance per `ServletContextHandler`.