# Jetty proxy servlet to route multiple requests

Tags: java, proxy, jetty

I have Jetty Servlet extending ProxyServlet class. Jetty Servlet's implementation proxy a request and forward to a destination IP address. Its one to one mapping. Since jetty server performs one to one communication, I am wondering If its possible to use same jetty servlet to proxy more than one requests? If any one knows about it or have any good example link, please share.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a confusing question (essentially, you are asking "how can I use the ProxyServlet in ways that are not a Proxy?"), can you elaborate what you expect the behavior to be?

Comment: My JettyServlet class extends ProxyServlet class and this is just proxying one request and route it to its destination. I want to do the same thing for multiple requests. Let's say I have 5 requests coming and I want to proxy each one and forward to its destination.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312637/jetty-how-to-add-a-servlet-to-multiple-servletcontexthandler-or-apply-containerr

Comment: Still not clear.  The `ProxyServlet` works for as many requests you throw at it, it doesn't just stop functioning after the first request.

Comment: Yes. Its correct that The ProxyServlet works for as many requests you throw at it. My issue is: Based on single request, I need to proxy multiple requests and forward them. Hope this makes sense now.

Comment: Basically there are some identifiers which decide the url by overriding rewriteURI function of ProxyServlet to which it would redirect. Initially we only had 1 identifier. Now we can have multiple identifiers and then based on the number of identifiers, we will redirect those many calls and then take the response from all the redirects or forwards and consolidate them in 1 response.